# How do I find the percentage of messages sent that received a response within a minute?

Tags: sql

I have a table called `messages` which contains IM records between the senders and the recipients.

The 4 fields are: Date, Timestamp Senderid, Recipientid.

How do I find the percentage of messages sent that received a response within a minute?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: what version and flavor of SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @RespondedMessagesCount INT = 
(Select Count(*) from messages m1

INNER JOIN messages m2
on m1.sender = m2.recipient
and m1.recipient = m1.sender

WHERE ABS(DateDiff(minute, m1.Date, m2.Date)) < 1),
@AllMessagesCount INT = (Select count(*) from messages)

Select Cast(@RespondedMessagesCount as float)/@AllMessagesCount * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but here is my answer for MySQL

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE messages
    (`Date` varchar(25), `Timestamp` varchar(25), `Senderid` Int, `Recipientid` Int )
;

INSERT INTO messages
    (`Date`, `Timestamp`,  `Senderid`, `Recipientid`  )
VALUES
    ('2017-02-27', '21:28:23', 1, 2),
    ('2017-02-27', '21:28:26', 2, 1),
    ('2017-02-27', '21:28:27', 1, 4),
    ('2017-02-27', '21:29:28', 4, 1),
    ('2017-02-27', '21:28:28', 3, 1)
;
```

Query:

```
select 
100*(
  SELECT count(*) FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      msg.Recipientid as Senderid,
      msg.Senderid as Recipientid,  
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CONCAT(messages.Date,' ',messages.Timestamp), CONCAT(msg.Date,' ',msg.Timestamp)) as seconds
    FROM messages 
      INNER JOIN messages msg ON messages.Recipientid=msg.Senderid
    WHERE
      msg.Recipientid=messages.Senderid
    ) as results
  WHERE seconds<=60 AND seconds>0
)/ (SELECT count(*) FROM messages)
```

Here is working example [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49e74c/8)

Comment: Looks like you're an expert to me :-)

Comment: is there a way to do this assuming the system doesn't allow for in-line sql statements? I am not that advanced so I am trying to understand it in a more basic sql lehman simplistic way. So perhaps MySQL syntax will help me understand. If you don't mind explaining the inner join as well. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know is there a way - sorry - but you can ask another question on stackoverflow about this. Google: "inner join graphic" e.g.: blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins . Above answer have many (nested) SELECT statements - run them separately to better understand each one.